# For what reason should Django try to automatically call the argument in a field lookup?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
>>> d = {'AUD': 1, 'GBP': 2}
>>> Currency.objects.filter(currency_code__in=d)
[<Currency: Australia Dollar (AUD)>, <Currency: United Kingdom Pound (GBP)>]
>>> Currency.objects.filter(currency_code__in=d.keys())
[<Currency: Australia Dollar (AUD)>, <Currency: United Kingdom Pound (GBP)>]
```

OK makes sense.  But:

```
>>> Currency.objects.filter(currency_code__in=d.keys)
[<Currency: Australia Dollar (AUD)>, <Currency: United Kingdom Pound (GBP)>]
```

WTF?  Why Django tries to call an argument I sent in?  It's necessary for what feature?
I really expected different, because of course:

```
>>> d.keys
<function keys>
>>> 'AUD' in d.keys
# TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

Comment: I believe because d.keys is evaluated as a function and not simply passed as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an undocumented and untested feature that is deprecated in 1.7, see the relevant deprecation proposal: [Deprecate callable QuerySet filter arguments](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11629).

FYI, the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f403653cf146384946e5c879ad2a351768ebc226/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1074) part that was doing it.

According to the [Django deprecation process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/), it would [fire up a `DeprecationWarning`](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f1b3ab9c2158f5a7da113aef4158499ce2d42ee2) in 1.7 and 1.8 and would be eventually removed in 1.9:

> Callable arguments for querysets were an undocumented feature that was
>   unreliable. It's been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
>
> Callable arguments were evaluated when a queryset was constructed
>   rather than when it was evaluated, thus this feature didn't offer any
>   benefit compared to evaluating arguments before passing them to
>   queryset and created confusion that the arguments may have been
>   evaluated at query time.